# Unparseable date issue with java time offset

Tags: java, android, date-parsing

So I am receiving date in `2017-01-01T01:34:00+00:00` format from server and I have below `SimpleDateFormatter` picked up after seeing many examples.

```
SimpleDateFormat serverToClientFormat=
                 new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",Locale.getDefault());
```

But when I try to parse it with below lines

```
serverToClientFormat.parse(object.getString("date"))
```

the string received from server to date format, it throws

**java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-01-01T01:34:00+00:00"**

What probably could I try else to parse above format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the literal `Z` instead of the `Z` pattern letter - so your format expects the letter Z in the input, not a time zone offset.

Also, the `Z` pattern doesn't accept the `:` in the offset. [Try with `X` instead](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (without the single quotes) and it should work fine:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/L2IMgM)

Comment: Sorry, but even after changing to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'X'` it was throwing same exception.. :(

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: Of course it is, `'X'` means you're expecting the character `X` there. None of your other format characters is in `'`, why put that one in `'`?

Comment: Sorry @T.J.Crowder .. Not familiar much with these literals, so got bit confused.. I get it now.. :)

Comment: @assylias.. Sorry but that's throwing `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'` Anything wrong here?

Comment: Ok.. I had to change it to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` rather and it worked.. Thanks much for your efforts.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao It was introduced in later versions of the API - that may be the reason.